# How to access image tag inside iframe with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to close a popup iframe to do web scraping in aliexpress, but i can't access the image to click it

link: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000094534783.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4e024c1e5Hpt1O&algo_pvid=501da7fc-b3f5-46a9-bbbc-75c7bed32f81&algo_expid=501da7fc-b3f5-46a9-bbbc-75c7bed32f81-20&btsid=0b0a555716045883196526344e54cc&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

[Where i want to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYimC.png)

This is my code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

option = Options()
option.set_headless(True)
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'fr')

def webscraping_aliexpress():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=f"{os.getcwd()}\geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)
    driver.get(str(input("Paste aliexpress url: ")))
    name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@class='product-title-text']").text
    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-price-current']").text
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@data-spm-anchor-id='a2g0o.detail.0.i4.4bc257b6555T2w'")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='rax-image ']"))).click()

webscraping_aliexpress()
```

I can extract some data, like name and price before popup shows on, but he block other operations after.

Comment: is your problem, not being able to close the popup or multiple popups randomly popping?

Comment: only one popup appears, but I can't close it

Answer (score 0):

You need switch content to iframe

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "__poplayer")]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
# code of closing popup here
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```